Building a dictionary from input (haven't found any answers for the part I need)
Basically, I'm wanting to create a dictionary of words and values directly from input, without using frequency or counting. I'm pretty sure I'm close, but I can't figure out how to make it take more than a single set. Here's the code I have so far:
def build_dictionary(words):
    return{str(input()):str(int(input()))}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = input().split()
    your_dictionary = build_dictionary(words)
    sorted_keys = sorted(your_dictionary.keys())
    for key in sorted_keys:
        print(f'{key} - {str(your_dictionary[key])}')

Do I need to use a for loop somewhere, or is there something else I need to do besides/in addition to that?
I've tried running it as-is, which initially had me input something that seemed to do nothing at all, then the actual desired input, and that worked for the first set, but then it stopped there. After that, I tried inputting the desired number of iterations in that blank space at the start, but got the same end result. I was hoping to have it repeat the process for a number of times designated via input.

What kind of input are you hoping to provide here?

"which initially had me input something that seemed to do nothing at all" - build_dictionary doesn't do anything with the words parameter.  Did you mean to use that instead of calling input() twice again?

A set of words such as apples, oranges, etc. (the keys), and a number associated with each one read as an integer (the values). I also need the number of pairs to be entered to be read from input as an integer, with that becoming the number of iterations of the other set of input. Does that make sense at all?

You need to experiment and learn more. But for this question:
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = dict()
    for line in sys.stdin:
        key, val = line.strip().split()
        words[key] = val
    for key in sorted(words.keys()):
        print(f'{key} - {words[key]}')

Enter your key and val per line separated by a whitespace.
If you done, press Ctrl-D in Linux/Unix/Mac or Ctrl-Z in DOS/Windows.
